# DLX assembly synthax

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems, computer-engineering

I see some example of DLX assembly instructions such as:

`LW Ri, 0 (Rz)`

but I can't find out why `Rz` has brackets around it.

Comment: I don't see any brackets around Rz, only parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, "Rn" means "the contents of register n" and "(Rn)" means the "data in the memory location whose address is in register Rn".

For memory access, you can also add a constant to (Rn), so 4(R8) means "add 4 to the address in register 8 (but don't change the data that is in R8!), and use the data in that memory location".

See [The DLX Instruction Set Architecture](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS378/2015sp/lectures/DLX.pdf) for examples (e.g. on Page 8.)

Comment: So this is just a notation thing right? But I still need to know what LW does to understand this statement. It's not completely clear to me why there's a different syntax for this case.